# Python extract unit of measure and attached number from column of string in Excel

Tags: python, excel, string, text, extract

I have to extract for each string in over 1000 of rows, the unit of measure and the associated number, like:

```
25 kg, 1000L
```

The string looks like this:

```
ZALTATA MA177-445 IBCC 1000L
```

The number is before the measurement unit.

Comment: You example is ambiguous, you should first determine the rules to decide what is a valid unit. For instance could `445 IBCC` be a match?

Comment: Without more clarity (as suggested by @mozway) it is hard to know how to proceed in terms of providing advice or suggestions. That said, I suggest you take a bit of time to read up on [regular expressions](https://towardsdatascience.com/regex-with-python-b4c5ca7c1eba). They may be daunting at first if you've never come across them but they are extremely powerful for pulling information out of text once you learn to use them.

Comment: @mozway valid unit is up to 4 digits before unit measure :KG and L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this example input:

```
                              col
0    ZALTATA MA177-445 IBCC 1000L
1  ZALTATA MA177 445 kg IBCC 1000
```

you could use `extract`:

```
import re
df['col'].str.extract(r'\b(?P<value>\d+)\s*(?P<unit>kg|l)\b', flags=re.I)
```

output:

```
  value unit
0  1000    L
1   445   kg
```

##### join and save

```
(df.join(df['col'].str.extract(r'\b(?P<value>\d+)\s*(?P<unit>kg|l)\b', flags=re.I))
   .to_excel('out.xslx')
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Just one more thing ,I need to add "value column" and" unit column" next to the description column and save it in excel.I am new in python your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can `join` and `to_excel` (see update)

Comment: .I am trying to read and understand your code.what each of these do \b,\d+,\S, ?P means

Comment: Those are standard regex expressions. `\b`: word boundary, `\d+`: one or more digit, `\s`: (not `\S`) space, `(?P<name>...)`: named capturing group.